# aws s3api list-objects-v2 display date and size in human readable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I would like to know how to display the date and size using aws s3api list-objects-v2

using the below commad:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket mybucket --prefix Videos --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='STANDARD_IA'].Key" --output text | sed 's/\t/\n/g'

Ouutput: 
Videos/test2/test2.mxf
Videos/mov2.mp4

My desired output:

1/18/2018  1.0 GiB Videos/test2/test2.mxf
1/18/2017  3.0 GiB Videos/mov2.mp4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) will not provide the output in that format, but you could take the CLI output and format it however you wish.

The most flexible is receiving JSON output and then reformatting it in a script (eg bash or python).

The normal `aws s3 ls` command almost gives the same output that you desire, but does not allow the `query` parameter you are using.